# Count repeated values in a column

Tags: count, formula, apple-numbers

I have a column of year values by which I am sorting. I'd like to find the quantity per year (read: number of repeats of each year value). I'd like to chart said values. I'm not sure how to make this happen.

I am using Apple's Numbers '08, but if possible a general solution that multiple people could use would be preferred.

Comment: If you were using Excel you could just be lazy and whip out a quick pivot table, but I don't know much about Numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the countif() function: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090291033.aspx

I did a similar thing to count how many hours of work there are for each upcoming version of my iPhone app. I was doing sumif(), but you just want countif().

See cells N4-N6 here: http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AhL0igVI9HVNdGpaS3U1cS1qOGVNd3h0Slg0a21vUWc&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

On a new sheet, list the unique years in one column, then their quantity count in the column next to them.  Select the entire range created, then create a chart.

I'm unsure from your question what you would specifically need more than this (and I work in Excel 2003).